# Superlatives in Spanish

Tags: gramática, superlativos

How do I translate *"Carla studies the most."* as in the following sentence.

> Maria studies more than Jim but Carla studies the most.

I understand comparatives, so

> Maria studies more than Jim. is <sub>Maria estudia más que Jim.</sub>

But the only formula that I know for Superlatives, is only in relation to adjectives.

For example

> Mateo es el estudiante **más inteligente**. or Mateo es el **más inteligente.**

but in relation to verbs I'm confused.

For example

> She **sings the best**.
>
> She **studies the most**.
>
> She **plays the worse**.

What is more confusing is that Google Translate gives the same Spanish comparative translation for both the English comparative and superlative translation.

Example

> She studies more. <sub>Ella estudia más.</sub>
>
> She studies the most. <sub>Ella estudia más.</sub>

UPDATE:

What about nouns? What is the superlative formula when dealing with nouns?

How would I translate the following

> She won the **most money**.

Comment: A common approach to this is as was suggested in the deleted answer: Estudia más que nadie.  Ganó más dinero que nadie.  Also: Es el más inteligente de toda la clase.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Good question. Indeed, there is no such structure in Spanish. You should never try to translate things like "the things I like **best**", not in a literal way.

The formula is saying "is the one who [verb] *más*".

For example:

Carla studies the most → Carla is the one who studies the most

> "Carla es la que más estudia"    *or*  "Carla es la que estudia más".

That's the easiest way. You can also say

Carla estudia (Como) la que más.

But I think that structure is more complicated.

Comment: I feel like "Carla es la que estudia más" is still comparative and not superlative. Just a gut feeling though.

Comment: It is not, altough it can be easily converted into a comparative. But, as it is written, it is superlative. Superlative means "more than anything/anyone, as in that sentence.

Comment: I've updated the question in relation to nouns. Please take a look.

Comment: Okay, again, it has no equivalent in Spanish. The formula would be the same: "the one who eartn most money": "Ella fue la que más dinero ganó"

Comment: Esta situación es similar a lo que pasa con las palabras de ubicación que tiene el inglés (**in**, **on**, **at**, **over**, **inside**) que son todas en general traducidas al español con la palabra "**en**". Para los que hablamos nativamente español y aprendemos inglés desdoblar "**en**" en varias palabras en inglés es muy complicado y confuso.

Answer (score 4):

For `Carla studies the most` you could plainly say

> Carla es la que más estudia (de todos)

You could even phrase it as

> Carla estudia la que más

Although this form is a little bit weird.

The second option is to say

> Carla es la más **[estudiosa](http://dle.rae.es/?id=H23zixx)**

So, with one option you would be saying

> "she is the one that does this the most/best"

and with the other

> "she is the most/best - *insert adjective here* -"

The adverb "[más](http://dle.rae.es/?id=OWErHxJ)" can be used for both comparative and **superlative**.

> Maria es **más** alta que Jim pero Carla es la **más** alta.

"Best" and "worse" can be translated respectively as "mejor" and "peor", so

> Ella es la que **mejor** canta
>
> Ella es la que **peor** toca

In `She studies more (Ella estudia más)`

that "más" indicates the degree that a property is greater or higher than other that is explicit or given by the context.

> Ella estudia más ahora que antes.  Ella estudia más que otros niños

`She studies the most.` uses a superlative. And you need to go with the forms "the most + *adj.*" or "the one that *does activity verb* the most".

Don't trust Google Translate, even if they claim it is really really accurate. It is a soulless robot that [doesn't really understand what is being said](https://www.indigoextra.com/blog/google-translate-funny-fails), and thus is [prone to EPIC fails](https://www.thelocal.es/20151102/galicia-celebrates-its-annual-clitoris-festival-thanks-to-google-translate).

Comment: También cabe _Carla estudia más que nadie_